# Find out the type hinting of a variable - PHP

Tags: php

Is there a way to find out what typehinting has been placed on a variable:

```
...function( IInterface $blah )
{
    if( gettypehint( $blah ) == IInterface )
    {
        echo "yay";
    }
}
```

I realise in this context this is pointless, but it's to simplify the question.

**Edit to help out answering:**

Actually the issue is that I am implementing a Factory kind of class. In that factory I need to know what the parameters were of the class that extends the Factory. If it is an IInterface then do a new ThingINeed, but if it was of type IPoopy then I need a new Poopy. kind of thing.

So i am after implementing a factory class that decides what class needs to be instanciated based off of the type hinting declared in the class implementing the factory.

**So my case is actually this:**

```
    public function AddBinding( $interface, $concrete )
    {
        $calledClass = get_called_class();
        $class = new \ReflectionClass( $calledClass );

        $method = $class->getMethod( "__construct" );
        $params = $method->getParameters();

        foreach( $params as $param )
        {
            if ( $param instanceof $interface )
            {
                return new $concrete();
            }
        }
    }
```

in reference to : [How to implement a factory class using PHP - Dependancy injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20471675/how-to-implement-a-factory-class-using-php-dependancy-injection)

Comment: Could it be http://www.php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.instanceof.php or http://es1.php.net/function.get-class ?

Comment: afaik it is impossible to call the function with something that does not derive from IInterface.
try call ...function("somethingNotfunction) - this will throw an error ...

Comment: Use `instanceof`? It works with interfaces, as demonstrated in example 4 here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.type.php

Comment: try: [ReflectionParameter::getClass](http://www.php.net/manual/reflectionparameter.getclass.php)

Answer (score 1):

As in ... checking the instance of the parameter?

`instanceof`: http://www.php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.instanceof.php

But considering you already assumed your parameter NEEDS to be an instanceOf IInterface, it might be a bit weird to doublecheck if PHP did it's work correctly.
Unless i'm missing something.

Comment: Actually the issue is that I am implementing a Factory kind of class. In that factory I need to know what the parameters were of the class that extends the Factory. If it is an IInterface then do a new ThingINeed, but if it was of type IPoopy then I need a new Poopy. kind of thing

Comment: The problem is that no instance of the object has yet to be made, so i can't do instanceof :(

Answer (score 1):

Your question seems to be odd. It can be resolved with [`ReflectionFunction`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionfunction.php) API:

```
function foo(StdClass $arg)
{
   $function = new ReflectionFunction(__FUNCTION__);
   $args     = array_map(function($item)
   {
      return $item->getClass()->getName();
   }, $function->getParameters());
   //var_dump($args);
   //so, if ($args[0]=='SomeNeededClass') { ... }
}

$obj = new StdClass();
foo($obj);
```

-but, really, I can't imagine use case for that - since, if it's your function, you are aware of it's arguments definition.

Comment: It's a follow on from this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20471675/how-to-implement-a-factory-class-using-php-dependancy-injection

Comment: If it's factory then it should know what it's doing. You can't have instantiation for all cases since it always is context-defined action

Comment: The problem I am solving is unit testing, I want to have one place that says "if a controller is passing IPageRepository $repo as a construct parameter then find out what type of object he has told me to make in the factory bindings" so that when unit testing, I can place in test data that uses a different repository still implementing the intrerface. A one stop place to say which repositories my application should be using

Comment: Well, in any case - you can use `ReflectionFunction` or `ReflectionMethod` to retrieve parameters like I've proposed above. If it's for some service purposes (or debug - which will be used only for tracing and understanding what's happening) - then it's ok. But using this for defining business-logic isn't a great idea since in most cases mixing data and meta-data is an anti-pattern

Comment: Yea, I haven't explained it well. There's no business logic in this. Unfortuantely I am using codeigniter which has a built in Controller feature set. So I am trying to do something similar to this with PHP:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660899(v=PandP.20).aspx for dependency injection