# Php - mysqli connect to db several times

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, dbconnection

I have an MVC framework that works like this:

```
/models/Mo_Sql.php (contains the connectdb function)
/models/Mo_ClassName1.php (that extends Mo_Sql)
/models/Mo_ClassName2.php (that extends Mo_Sql)
/models/Mo_ClassName...X.php (that extends Mo_Sql)
/models/... 

/rules/Ru_ClassName1.php (with private Mo_ClassName1)
/rules/Ru_ClassName2.php (with private Mo_ClassName2)
/rules/Ru_ClassName...X.php (with private Mo_ClassNameX)
/rules/Ru_......

/config/config.php with all Mo_ and Ru_ included and is called in every page of my site.
```

The concern that I have is that when i require_once config.php, this latter includes N Mo_ files and N Ru_ files, therefore upon construction, I believe there will be multiple db connections opened as every Mo_ file extend Mo_Sql.

My question : is it dangerous to proceed like this? Is there another way to call only once Mo_SQL and/or Mo_Sql->connectdb?

Thanks for your help

Comment: why don't you store the connection in a common place?

Comment: Can you indicate which mvc this happens to be?

Comment: Design your DB handler connection object in Singleton, and injected into the Model class using it.

Comment: Duplicate of recently bubbled up http://stackoverflow.com/a/18853389/285587

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Daniel stated, ideally you want a central point in your MVC that handles your database connections. This way it is accessibly in your entire project, plus you can easily keep track of how many connections are running at a time (preferably just one of course).

If you happen to be using a framework, look for a premade library that does these kinds of things. Most recent frameworks have something to handle this.

If you're just creating your own project in native `PHP` then you can just implement something that behaves like Daniel described.

Comment: It worked perfectly with a single connect Class, only one dbconnect per page now, thanks